# Color Picker Selected Color Display

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on an app which allows me to select a color. Currently, I have a simple button which says "Pick a Color" which launches a new modal with colors. Once, the user selects the color the "Pick a Color" text is replaced with the color name (requirement) and the button background is filled with the selected color. The problem arises when the selected color is same as the text color of the button. In that scenario the user will not be able to see the selected color text since it gets mixed with the background color.

How to deal with this issue?

Comment: use `[UIColor ClearColor]` as background color

Comment: Sorry my bad! This is a HTML 5 app using Javascript etc and NOT the native app.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a design issue more than anything else. If you have a UI guy/gal on the project, I would defer to their judgment in this case.

In [Spend Stack](http://www.dreaminginbinary.co/Software/Apps/iOS/SpendStack/SpendStack.html) I had a similar issue since the users can change their color scheme throughout the entire app, I eventually just made everything work with a white font color. In your instance, I am going to assume your font color is white as well. In that case, you could just add a condition to change the text color when white is selected easily by using one of the factory methods on `UIColor`:

```
lbl.textColor = [UIColor redColor]; //or whatever color you want
```

I would also just fire off a message regardless when a new background color is selected for scalability reasons.

A great example to look at is [Chameleon](https://github.com/VAlexander/Chameleon) which deals with the exact same issue you mentioned [image]

Best of luck!

Comment: But it is not only if white is selected then change the text color to black. What if off white is selected or a yellow is selected or a shade of yellow or gray. There are just too many combinations.

Comment: That's why I mentioned you should fire off a message regardless - to handle it every time. There is no way around this other than some elbow grease and code - if you want this to be dynamic you could just have a message that receives the chosen color and finds a complimentary color which could then be returned to your UILabel. Many ways to skin this cat.